# Discord FFMPEG doesnt play audio at all

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here's the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("You need to be in a voice channel to use this command.")
        return

    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice_client = await channel.connect()

    print('trying1')
    try:
        print('trying2')
        source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("zzzz.mp3")
        voice_client.play(source)

        print('trying3')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while playing the music: {e}")
    print('trying')
```

All it says is:

[2023-06-25 02:30:01] [INFO    ] discord.voice_client: Connecting to voice...
[2023-06-25 02:30:01] [INFO    ] discord.voice_client: Starting voice handshake... (connection attempt 1)
[2023-06-25 02:30:01] [INFO    ] discord.voice_client: Voice handshake complete. Endpoint found russia5225.discord.media

nothing more, it doesnt even play music and it doesnt go further to print('trying1'), whats wrong?

tried everything, giving executable param and debugging

Comment: If you are running this locally on Windows, have you installed ffmpeg and provided correct absolute path in your executable param?

Comment: Have you installed the discord voice module `python3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]
` and ffmpeg (not on the pip installer, but you have to manually install it) too?

Comment: yeah guys i installed everything you told me, still doesnt work, i checked if ffmpeg work by typing "ffmpeg" in cmd and yes it works

Comment: Pixie, thank you very much! It helped me! ILY LOL